# Displaying a content managed image in a Umbraco 6 MVC website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco, umbraco6

I'm working on my first Umbraco 6 MVC website, its just took me about an hour to work out how to display a content managed image in a razor view. It cant be that hard, I must be missing something...

This is what I ended up with...

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!Doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>blah</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <img src="@Umbraco.TypedMedia(Int32.Parse(Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("siteLogo").ToString())).GetPropertyValue("umbracoFile")"/>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

... which seems overly complicated to just display an image? Surely this cant be best practice using razor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things here:

- You don't need to cast the property value to an `Int32`, as `TypeMedia()` accepts a `string` or `object` id parameter.
- You can use the `Url` property of the `IPublishedContent` instead of `GetPropertyValue("umbracoFile")`

So it becomes:

```
<img src="@Umbraco.TypedMedia(Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("siteLogo")).Url"/>
```

Which is much nicer isn't it? There are obviously many ways to shortne this, extension methods but one that a friend showed me recently was [uMapper](http://ucomponents.org/umapper/) which allows you to create strongly typed objects corresponding to your document types, working much like AutoMapper. For a little leg work up front, your code can become much more understandable and concise.